# Pycharm cannot find interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I have python 3.9.0 but I cannot get pycharm to use it.  I go to settings and click on python interpreter and it says "nothing to show".  I don't get the option to add one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jonathan i think this is the right way:

Go to preferences --> project:  --> python intepreter --> click on the little wheel thing top right corner --> find your enviroment go to bin and select python.exe

so:

[image]

Comment: I get no wheel in the top right when I get to the Python Interpreter page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File | Settings | Project: <project_name> | Project Interpreter (Preferences | Project: <project_name> | Project Interpreter for macOS) to find where your environment/interpreter is located